# JQuery Multiple Fade Out

Tags: jquery

I have a quick question with some jQuery where I'm running into a problem.  My client wants me to have an absolutely positioned/overflow hidden div that loads on the screen before the website loads.  Essentially he wants to highlight an event with a flyer and then fade into the page. Well, I've got all that.  Now he wants to fade into an event list prior to fading into the website itself.  So, there will be the flyer, then fade into an event list, then fade into the web page.  I'm trying to manipulate the code, but nothing is working.  Here's what I've been using for the first fade:

```
jQuery('.cws').load(function() {
});
jQuery(window).load(function () {
jQuery('#mask').delay(4500).fadeOut(2500);
jQuery('body').css("overflow", "visible");
jQuery('#mp3').attr("autostart", "true");
```

});

I'm needing to fade into the new .event-list-container div prior to fading and changing the body css to visible.  I tried putting a delay function for the CWS in prior to to the window load function, but that then just fades into a blank page; it's weird.  Anyways, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hehe.

```
$("...").load();
```

is ajax request, you meant

```
$("...").ready(function(){});
```

, didn't you ?

Comment: as a matter of fact, yes haha